# Problems With CppStyle plugin on eclipse

Tags: eclipse-cdt, clang-format

I would like to use the CppStyle Plugin in Eclipse within my projects
I have installed the plugin in Eclipse, installed clang-format on my MAC, and set Preferences->C/C++->CodeStyle->Formatter code formatter to 'CppStyle(clang-format)'

But when i try to format my code on eclipse, the console warns 'clang-format () does not exist.'

Does any body know how to install CppStyle properly?

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, it seems like i forget setting the clang-format path in eclipse.
You can find the setting in Preferences->C/C++->CppStyle